# How use multiple :not() in LESS?

Tags: css, less

I have this

```
.views-field:not(.views-field-nothing)
        {
          background-color: #f2f3f1;
          border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
          border-radius: 4px;
          margin-bottom: 7px;  
      }
```

This is funcional, but i need to do a multiple .not, I tested with:
`.views-field:not(.views-field-nothing,.b,.c)` but this was nonfuncional, 
also I tested with this:
`.views-field:not(.views-field-nothing):not(.a):not(.b)` but this was nonfuncional.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you're targeting?

Comment: what elements are you trying to target? Some examples would help

Answer (score 3):

`:not()` selectors should work in LESS just like they do in CSS, to chain them together just add them one after the other `:not(.this):not(.that)`.

```css
p:not(.a):not(.c) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="a">A</p>
<p class="b">B</p>
<p class="c">C</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
.views-field:not(.views-field-nothing):not(.a):not(.b) {
    background-color: #f2f3f1;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;  
}
```

The fact that you've already tried this and it isn't working suggests that there's something else at fault, probably with your markup.